# Representing a tensor in terms of a matrix

Tags: tensors

How can we show a tensor map in to some matrix representation? For instance if we have some tensor $T$ is a $(1,1)$ tensor on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ given by:

$$T =\sum_{i=1}^n dx^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i+n}}$$

Can anyone show me how this tensor will have an explicit matrix representation respect to some basis $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\}$ for $i=1,...2n?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $(1, 1)$-tensor $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ can be written as

$$T = \sum_{i, j = 1}^{2n}T_{ij}\,dx^i\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}.$$

The matrix representation of $T$ is then the $2n \times 2n$ matrix $[T_{ij}]$.

For the tensor in your question, we have

$$T_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & 1 \leq i \leq n, j = i + n\\
0 &\ \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

It follows that the matrix representation of $T$ is

$$\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 0 & I_n\\
 \hline
 0 & 0
\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: Isn't is supposed to be for $ i=j+n?$ because I cant seem to show why that matrix representation holds.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis: Sorry, the matrix I gave was incorrect. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for the fast correction, really confused me. Now I feel much better.